# Creating a bootstrapTable with dynamic headers / React

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to render a BootstrapTable with dynamic headers in a class. My class is a grid with only this table in it. I got code from Bootstrap and rendered a table with headers with no problem. The thing here is I don't know how many headers my table will have and what information it will contain. I tried running a for() in my return but React blocks me from doing so. I want to render only one *< BoostrapTable>* but multiple *< TableHeaderColumn>*.

A piece of my code if it helps: (I'm using React)

This code shows how the TableHeaderColumns are right now but of course when they are dynamic, I should only need to call the function **initiateHeaders**

```
render () {
console.log("actionsGrid Props:  ", this.props);

function initiateHeaders(totalCount) {
  for(let i=0; i<totalCount; i++) {
    createColumns(i);
  }
}
return (
  <div>
    <BootstrapTable hover data={action} pagination>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='actionId' dataFormat={actionIdFormatter}
        isKey
        dataSort={true}>
        Request #
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='process' dataSort={true}>
        Process
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='action' dataFormat={actionFormatter} dataSort={true}>
        Action
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='created' dataSort={true}>
        Created
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='timeLimit' dataFormat={timeLimitFormatter} dataSort={true}>
        TimeLimit
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='subject' dataSort={true}>
        Subject
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='approval_1' dataSort={true}>
        Approval of the Level 1
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      {initiateHeaders(6)}
    </BootstrapTable>
  </div>
);
}

function createColumns(totalCount) {

  return(
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='data' dataSort={true}>
            Title here
    </TableHeaderColumn>
  )
}
```

For now, the createColumns function isn't dynamic but I'll change the info in it when the code works.

Thank you

EDIT:

TL.DR: Fetching information to make headers in a bootstrapTable but the number of headers change depending on the process. Need to render them dynamically.

Comment: To dumb down my question: I want to be able to return multiple < TableHeaderColumn> from a function to the render() of the class.

Comment: Sorry I can't tell who upvoted - if my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it. If not, let me know more so I can try to help. Thanks!

Comment: Of course! I just upvoted without accepting it because I'm trying it out right now. It looks like it should work, I'm just making sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) function. I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but this is generally how you could build your table header columns, assuming the object that holds all your column data is called `columnData`:

```
render() {
  const tableHeaderColumns = this.props.columnData.map((column) => (
    <TableHeaderColumn 
      dataField={column.action} 
      dataFormat={column.actionFormatter}
      dataSort={column.dataSort}
    >
      {column.description}
    </TableHeaderColumn>
  ))

  return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable hover data={action}>
        {tableHeaderColumns}
      </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is a common design pattern in React. `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` are used much more than `for` loops, for example. Not mutating data is important to optimize performance in React, so that is part of the reason why.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.