# React - Using "props..." as dataField to pass in a table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I' currently trying to render a BootstrapTable with dynamic headers and dynamic information. I figured out how to make the headers dynamically using this piece of code:

```
const tableHeaderColumns = this.props.data.viewer.actions.items[0].request.dataset.
items.map((data) => (

  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={data.name}>

    {data.description}

  </TableHeaderColumn>
))
```

which can be found in my other question: [Creating a bootstrapTable with dynamic headers / React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135323/creating-a-bootstraptable-with-dynamic-headers-react)

What I'm trying to do is adding the dynamic information in my function that adds the information in the table.

```
function addAction (quantity, props) {
  action = []
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    action.push({
      actionId: props.items[i].request.number,
      process: props.items[i].request.process.description,

      props.items[i].request.dataset.items[0].name: 'Hello'
    }); 
  }
}
```

Basically, actionId and process are **dataField** of a column in my table. I'm trying to use the ***props.items[i]...*** as a dataField of my new dynamically created columns.

The error shown is in the way I write "*props.items...* : Hello".

The arrow points to the dot after *props*.

I'm pretty sure the problem is there because if I replace the **props.items{}** by any single word, no more bug, but the info is not transmitted.

Thank you

Comment: So if you want the ```items[0].name``` value to become a key of the object, you need to wrap it in brackets during the object expression so that it is evaluated as a key. Like this: ```[props.items[i].request.dataset.items[0].name]: 'Hello'```

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple... Usually you have to wrap it in curly brackets no?

Comment: @MichaelLyons add that as an answer with explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're trying to set keys in an object with a dynamic value. This is actually quite simple.

Within your Object expression, you'll want to wrap the value in square brackets like so:

```
[props.items[i].request.dataset.items[0].name]: 'Hello'
```

This will tell Javascript to evaluate the variable you're using as a key within the object.

Hope this helps.